# Better way to organize Inheritance and relationship between classes

Tags: c++, qt, logic

I have a problem with logical structure of my project:

```
class AbstractItem : public QObject{
public:
    AbstractItem() {}
    int id;
    QString name;
};

class BiggestItem : public AbstractItem
{
public:
    BiggestItem() {}
    //Item can contains a lot of specific parameters
    int specificForBiggest1;
    //Item must contains lists of smaller items and groups
    QList<BigItem *> m_bigItems;
    QList<Group *> m_bigItemGroups;
};

class BigItem : public AbstractItem
{
public:
    BigItem() {}
    //Item can contains a lot of specific parameters
    int specificForBig1;
    //Item must contains lists of smaller items and groups
    QList<MediumItem *> m_mediumItems;
    QList<Group *> m_mediumItemGroups;
signals:
    void mediumItemsChanged(QList<MediumItem *> mediumItems);
public slots:
    void setMediumItems(const QList<MediumItem *> &mediumItems)
    {
        if(m_mediumItems == mediumItems)
            return;

        m_mediumItems = mediumItems;
        emit mediumItemsChanged(m_mediumItems);
    }
};

class MediumItem : public AbstractItem
{
public:
    MediumItem() {}
    //Item can contains a lot of specific parameters
    int specificForMedium1;
    QList<SmallItemType1 *> m_smallItemsType1;
    QList<SmallItemType2 *> m_smallItemsType2;

    QList<Group *> m_smallItemsType1Groups;
    QList<Group *> m_smallItemsType2Groups;
signals:
    void smallItemsType1Changed(QList<SmallItemType1 *> smallItemsType1);
    void smallItemsType2Changed(QList<SmallItemType2 *> smallItemsType2);
public slots:
    void setSmallItemsType1(const QList<SmallItemType1 *> &smallItemsType1)
    {
        if(m_smallItemsType1 == smallItemsType1)
            return;

        m_smallItemsType1 = smallItemsType1;
        emit smallItemsType1Changed(m_smallItemsType1);
    }
    void setSmallItemsType2(const QList<SmallItemType2 *> &smallItemsType2)
    {
        if(m_smallItemsType2 == smallItemsType2)
            return;

        m_smallItemsType2 = smallItemsType2;
        emit smallItemsType2Changed(m_smallItemsType2);
    }
};

class AbstractSmallItem : public AbstractItem
{
public:
    AbstractSmallItem() {}
    int param1;
    int param2;
    //... a lot of parameters
    int param99;
signals:
    void param1Changed(int param1);
    void param2Changed(int param2);
    //...
    void param99Changed(int param99);
};

class SmallItemType1 : public AbstractSmallItem
{
public:
    SmallItemType1() {
        param1 = 0;
        param2 = 10;
        //... a lot of default values
        param99 = 123;
    }
};
class SmallItemType2 : public AbstractSmallItem
{
public:
    SmallItemType2() {
        param1 = 35;
        param2 = 15;
        //... a lot of default values
        param99 = 67;
    }
};

class Group
{
public:
    Group() {}
    QList<AbstractItem *> itemList;
    AbstractItem * m_masterItem;
    void addItem(AbstractItem *i){
        if(itemList.isEmpty())
        {
            auto isBig = qobject_cast<BigItem*>(i);
            if (isBig != 0) {
                m_masterItem = new BigItem();
                auto mI = qobject_cast<BigItem*>(m_masterItem);
                mI->m_mediumItems.append(isBig->m_mediumItems);
                //1 parameters - 2 connections
                QObject::connect(mI,&BigItem::mediumItemsChanged,
                                 isBig,&BigItem::setMediumItems);
                QObject::connect(isBig,&BigItem::mediumItemsChanged,
                                 mI,&BigItem::setMediumItems);
            }
            auto isMedium = qobject_cast<MediumItem*>(i);
            if (isMedium != 0) {
                m_masterItem = new MediumItem();
                auto mI = qobject_cast<MediumItem*>(m_masterItem);
                mI->m_smallItemsType1.append(isMedium->m_smallItemsType1);
                mI->m_smallItemsType2.append(isMedium->m_smallItemsType2);
                //****Connect signals and slots

                //2 parameters - 4 connections
                //****
            }
            auto isSmallType1 = qobject_cast<SmallItemType1*>(i);
            if (isSmallType1 != 0) {
                m_masterItem = new SmallItemType1();
                //Cast masterItem and connect signals and slots
                //but a lot of parameters need to a lot^2 connections
            }
            auto isSmallType2 = qobject_cast<SmallItemType2*>(i);
            if (isSmallType2 != 0) {
                m_masterItem = new SmallItemType2();
                //Cast masterItem and connect signals and slots
                //but a lot of parameters need to a lot^2 connections
            }
        }
        itemList.append(i);
    }

    void removeItem(AbstractItem *i){
        if(itemList.contains(i))
            itemList.removeOne(i);
    }
};
```

Which way better?

1. Create all pure virtual methods of Items class in abstractItem class and do not use qobject_cast?
2. Create some Group class (BigItemGroup, MediumItemGroup etc.), inherited from AbstractGroup, implement methods and do not use use qobject_cast?
3. Use template class if it possible?
4. Something else?

I'm stumped. Thanx!

Comment: We have no context for what you're trying to do. Could you add some explanation regarding the project you're working on? What are you trying to make, or what issues are you trying to fix? And why you have params 1 through 99 in a class (as opposed to using an array?)

Comment: I'm add params1-params99 only for example. On real application all it params have a different type and using for different situations. And actually i will have less than 100 params (about 30-50).

Comment: That's application is gui control software for multiple hardware devices over network and this classes is human understanding wrappers. Sometimes some parameters in some devices need to be linked and controlled together. Sometimes not.

Comment: I'm try to find better way to write less code with this class hierarchy and minimize double coding.